# How to add a hotkey Enter in a JPanel class?

Tags: java, swing, hotkeys, enter

First, I know how to add an Enter hotkey with the following code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//...
JButton button = new JButton("Execute");
panel.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button); // Hotkey "Enter" by default
// ...
panel.add(button);
```

But in this case, the following code below

```
class LeftPanel extends JPanel
{
    LeftPanel()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(2, 42, 146, 252);

        button();
    }

    void button() 
    {       
        JButton exebutton = new JButton("Execute");
        //getRootPane().setDefaultButton(exebutton); // Hotkey "Enter" by default
        exebutton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Shortcut: Alt + Enter
        exebutton.setBounds(4, 18, 138, 47);
        add(exebutton);
    }
}
```

How do I add the Enter hotkey? `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(exebutton);` does not work. I got an error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

This is my frame class

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{   
    MyFrame()
    {
        setTitle("Frame Test");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLayout(null);

        LeftPanel leftpanel = new LeftPanel();
        add(leftpanel);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

and my main

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new MyFrame();
}
```

`Alt+Enter` shortcut works, but not `Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(exebutton);` in your MyFrame class like this

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{   
    MyFrame()
    {
        setTitle("Frame Test");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLayout(null);

        LeftPanel leftpanel = new LeftPanel();
        add(leftpanel);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(leftpanel.getDefaultBtn());

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Make sure you can access your JButton by declaring it before any of the methods like so

```
class LeftPanel extends JPanel
{
    JButton exeButton;

    LeftPanel()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(2, 42, 146, 252);

        button();
    }

    void button() 
    {       
        exebutton = new JButton("Execute");
        exebutton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Shortcut: Alt + Enter
        exebutton.setBounds(4, 18, 138, 47);
        add(exebutton);
    }

    public JButton getDefaultBtn()
    {
        return exebutton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I notice the compiler is advincing me to declare the JButton outside too

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. :)

Comment: @LordRixuel, You should create a method if you want to access the button outside the panel, don't access a variable of the class directly.

Comment: @camickr I will try. Thank you very much for the suggestion

Comment: If you need help with the method, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the default button in the constructor of your LeftPanel class because the panel has not been added to the JFrame yet, so it doesn't know what the root pane is.

So in your LeftPanel you need to do a couple of things:

1. Make your "execButton" an instance variable, not a local variable.
2. Create a method like `getDefaultButton()` which will simply return the instance variable.

Now in you code when you create the frame you can set the default button:

```
LeftPanel leftpanel = new LeftPanel();
add(leftpanel);
getRootPane().setDefaultButton( leftPanel.getDefaultButton() );
```

Also, get rid of all the null layouts in your code. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, which doesn't require changing the main in any way. Add this to your `JPanel` subclass:

```
@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(exebutton);
}
```

This works because when a panel is layed out (e.g. by calling `setVisible()`) the method `addNotify()` is called all the way down the component tree.

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6287283/1052284)